# Can't add build_verify package

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I wanted to create a new project using riverpod and followed some tutorials.
I first followed [Riverpod Docs](https://riverpod.dev/docs/introduction/getting_started#installing-the-package) and added:

```
flutter pub add hooks_riverpod
flutter pub add flutter_hooks
flutter pub add riverpod_annotation
flutter pub add dev:riverpod_generator
flutter pub add dev:build_runner
flutter pub add dev:custom_lint
flutter pub add dev:riverpod_lint
```

pubspec.yaml

```yaml
...
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.3 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  hooks_riverpod: ^2.4.9
  flutter_hooks: ^0.20.4
  riverpod_annotation: ^2.3.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  riverpod_generator: ^2.3.9
  build_runner: ^2.4.7
  custom_lint: ^0.5.7
  riverpod_lint: ^2.3.7
```

After looking at this video [Diving into Riverpod](https://www.youtube.com/live/BJtQ0dfI-RA?si=Tuf0qholDJPicgr5&t=725), I wanted to add `build_verify` package so I did this:

```
flutter pub add dev:build_verify
```

Then I get error:

```
Note: test_api is pinned to version 0.6.0 by flutter_test from the flutter SDK.
See https://dart.dev/go/sdk-version-pinning for details.

The current Dart SDK version is 3.1.3.

Because test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.8 <1.16.3 depends on web_socket_channel ^1.0.0 and test >=0.12.0-beta.3 <1.16.0-nullsafety.8 doesn't support null safety, test >=0.12.0-beta.3 <1.16.3 requires
  web_socket_channel ^1.0.0.
And because test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.19 <1.16.6 depends on test_api 0.2.19, test >=0.12.0-beta.3 <1.16.6 requires web_socket_channel ^1.0.0 or test_api 0.2.19.
And because test >=1.16.6 <1.17.10 depends on analyzer ^1.0.0 and test >=1.17.10 <1.20.0 depends on analyzer >=1.0.0 <3.0.0, test >=0.12.0-beta.3 <1.20.0 requires web_socket_channel ^1.0.0 or
  test_api 0.2.19 or analyzer >=1.0.0 <3.0.0.
And because test >=1.20.0 <1.21.2 depends on test_api 0.4.9 and test >=1.21.0 <1.21.6 depends on analyzer >=2.0.0 <5.0.0, test >=0.12.0-beta.3 <1.21.6 requires web_socket_channel ^1.0.0 or
  test_api 0.2.19 or 0.4.9 or analyzer >=1.0.0 <5.0.0.
And because test >=1.21.6 <1.24.4 depends on analyzer >=2.0.0 <6.0.0 and test >=1.24.4 <1.25.0 depends on test_api 0.6.1, test >=0.12.0-beta.3 <1.25.0 requires web_socket_channel ^1.0.0 or
  test_api 0.2.19 or 0.4.9 or 0.6.1 or analyzer >=1.0.0 <6.0.0.
And because test >=1.25.0 depends on test_api 0.7.0 and every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on test_api 0.6.0, if flutter_test from sdk and test >=0.12.0-beta.3 then web_socket_channel
  ^1.0.0 or analyzer >=1.0.0 <6.0.0.
And because riverpod_lint >=2.2.1 depends on analyzer ^6.0.0 and build_runner >=2.0.0 depends on web_socket_channel ^2.0.0, one of flutter_test from sdk or test >=0.12.0-beta.3 or riverpod_lint
  >=2.2.1 or build_runner >=2.0.0 must be false.
And because build_verify >=2.0.0 depends on test ^1.0.0 and build_verify <2.0.0 doesn't support null safety, one of flutter_test from sdk or riverpod_lint >=2.2.1 or build_runner >=2.0.0 or
  build_verify any must be false.
And because your_app_name depends on both build_verify any and flutter_test from sdk, riverpod_lint >=2.2.1 is incompatible with build_runner >=2.0.0.
So, because your_app_name depends on both build_runner ^2.4.7 and riverpod_lint ^2.3.7, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=1.8.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.0.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
```

How can I add `build_verify`?